# How to set Search type in share-intent

Tags: android, android-intent

How to set Search type in using share-intent.I need to search a string in twitter facebook and other social media applications

> Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
>   shareIntent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "Hello");

I have selected ACTION_SEARCH but what should be to the type

> shareIntent.setType("????");

If i'm not setting any search type lot of unwanted applications are coming up like maps, contacts.. I need to filter it out

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you mean by type, but everything you need to know is right here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Comment: setType is an explicit MIME data type. This is used to create intents that only specify a type and not data, eg: shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

Comment: hmm well your searching will always be plain/text right?  users can't put anything else in the search box..

Comment: yes . and i can give search query also(putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "Query");) the problem is it is give the option for searching maps, contacts,google.. I need to limit it to application search like twitter,facebook,Myspace